# UWP (Windows 10 App) InkCanvas LoadAsync Error HRESULT E_FAIL has been returned from a call to a COM component

Tags: xaml, uwp

I use InkCanvas in my UWP application that I developed as a Windows 10 App. I am successfully saving the drawing in JPG format to LocalStorage.

I want to load the drawing into the InkCanvas object so that it can be selected and rearranged over the DataGrid. I am encountering the following error.

Thank you so much if you help.

Exception:

> {System.Runtime.InteropServices.COMException (0x80004005): Error HRESULT E_FAIL has been returned from a call to a COM component.
> at Windows.UI.Input.Inking.InkStrokeContainer.LoadAsync(IInputStream inputStream)
> at TICAppUWP.CoverPage.canvasFileNotes()}

Save:

```
StorageFolder storageFolder = await StorageFolder.GetFolderFromPathAsync(fileNotesFolderPath);

            string fileName = App._PreparedFor +"_"+ App._Date + "_PageID_" + App._CoverPageID;
            var file = await storageFolder.CreateFileAsync(fileName + ".jpg", CreationCollisionOption.ReplaceExisting);

            CanvasDevice device = CanvasDevice.GetSharedDevice();
            CanvasRenderTarget renderTarget = new CanvasRenderTarget(device, (int)myInkCanvas.ActualWidth, (int)myInkCanvas.ActualHeight, 96);

            using (var ds = renderTarget.CreateDrawingSession())
            {
                ds.Clear(Windows.UI.Colors.White);
                ds.DrawInk(myInkCanvas.InkPresenter.StrokeContainer.GetStrokes());
            }

            using (var fileStream = await file.OpenAsync(FileAccessMode.ReadWrite))
            {
                await renderTarget.SaveAsync(fileStream, CanvasBitmapFileFormat.Jpeg, 1f);
            }
```

Load:

```
StorageFolder storageFolder = await StorageFolder.GetFolderFromPathAsync(fileNotesFolderPath);
            string fileName = App._PreparedFor + "_" + App._Date + "_PageID_" + App._CoverPageID;
            var file = await storageFolder.GetFileAsync(fileName + ".jpg");

            StorageFile inkFile = await storageFolder.GetFileAsync(fileName + ".jpg");

            if (file != null)
            {
                Windows.Storage.Streams.IRandomAccessStream stream = await file.OpenAsync(Windows.Storage.FileAccessMode.Read);

                using (var inputStream = stream.GetInputStreamAt(0))
                {
                    await myInkCanvas.InkPresenter.StrokeContainer.LoadAsync(stream);
                }

                stream.Dispose();
            }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> UWP (Windows 10 App) InkCanvas LoadAsync Error HRESULT E_FAIL has been returned from a call to a COM component

Please refer to `InkStrokeContainer` [document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.ui.input.inking.inkstrokecontainer.loadasync?view=winrt-22000#Windows_UI_Input_Inking_InkStrokeContainer_LoadAsync_Windows_Storage_Streams_IInputStream_) *Asynchronously loads all InkStroke objects from the specified stream to the InkStroke collection that is managed by the InkStrokeContainer.*

But you passed stream to `LoadAsync` method is image file stream but not InkStroke collection stream. so it will throw exception.

For this scenario, you need save InkStroke stream with [`SaveAsync`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.ui.input.inking.inkstrokecontainer.saveasync?view=winrt-22000#Windows_UI_Input_Inking_InkStrokeContainer_SaveAsync_Windows_Storage_Streams_IOutputStream_) method, but not save as image file.

Comment: Thanks you for your precious comment. As you stated, I got the solution with the StrokeContainer collection.